# can't enable xft and freetype support for emacs 25.2

Tags: 16.04, emacs, shared-library

This question relates to emacs compilation, but it is more about library lookup problem on Ubuntu so I think I should put here. If it is better to put over emacs forum, I will do that later.

Emacs 25.2 source code was downloaded from here: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/

I want to `configure` emacs 25.2 to support `xft`, `cairo`, `gnutls` and `gtk3` before compiling it. How do I do that?

I installed all dependencies I can think of below. There are so many `sudo apt-get` entries because I went back and forth trying to get the things to work:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep emacs24
sudo apt-get install libxft2
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev
sudo apt-get install libgnutls28-dev
sudo apt-get install libm17n-dev libxft-dev libotf-dev
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev
sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev
sudo apt-get install libharfbuzz-dev libpangoxft-1.0-0 libpango1.0-dev libpangoft2-1.0-0
sudo apt-get install libharfbuzz
sudo apt-get install libharfbuzz-dev libharfbuzz-bin
sudo apt-get install build-essential texinfo libx11-dev libxpm-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libgif-dev libtiff-dev libgtk2.0-dev libncurses-dev
```

After this, I also tried rebooting the computer, running `ldconfig -v` and see the libraries are actually listed in the verbose output.

And this is configure command which tries to enable `xft` for a start:

```
./configure --with-xft --with-x
```

Configure output:

```
Configured for 'x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'.

  Where should the build process find the source code?    .
  What compiler should emacs be built with?               gcc -g3 -O2
  Should Emacs use the GNU version of malloc?             yes
      (Using Doug Lea's new malloc from the GNU C Library.)
  Should Emacs use a relocating allocator for buffers?    no
  Should Emacs use mmap(2) for buffer allocation?         no
  What window system should Emacs use?                    x11
  What toolkit should Emacs use?                          LUCID
  Where do we find X Windows header files?                Standard dirs
  Where do we find X Windows libraries?                   Standard dirs
  Does Emacs use -lXaw3d?                                 yes
  Does Emacs use -lXpm?                                   yes
  Does Emacs use -ljpeg?                                  yes
  Does Emacs use -ltiff?                                  yes
  Does Emacs use a gif library?                           yes -lgif
  Does Emacs use a png library?                           yes -lpng12
  Does Emacs use -lrsvg-2?                                no
  Does Emacs use cairo?                                   no
  Does Emacs use imagemagick?                             no
  Does Emacs support sound?                               yes
  Does Emacs use -lgpm?                                   yes
  Does Emacs use -ldbus?                                  no
  Does Emacs use -lgconf?                                 no
  Does Emacs use GSettings?                               no
  Does Emacs use a file notification library?             yes -lglibc (inotify)
  Does Emacs use access control lists?                    yes -lacl
  Does Emacs use -lselinux?                               yes
  Does Emacs use -lgnutls?                                no
  Does Emacs use -lxml2?                                  yes
  Does Emacs use -lfreetype?                              no
  Does Emacs use -lm17n-flt?                              no
  Does Emacs use -lotf?                                   no
  Does Emacs use -lxft?                                   no
  Does Emacs directly use zlib?                           yes
  Does Emacs have dynamic modules support?                no
  Does Emacs use toolkit scroll bars?                     yes
  Does Emacs support Xwidgets (requires gtk3)?            no
```

Answer (score 0):

Holy moly molly

Turns out it is because `configure` could find some dependencies under my `$HOME/.linuxbrew`, i.e. `.linuxbrew/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.4/include/libxml2` so it keeps searching for other depencencies in the same directory. That's why despite many dependencies installed, they couldn't be found. After deleting `$HOME/.linuxbrew` because I don't use linuxbrew anymore, everyting works perfectly as expected. BTW, `linuxbrew` gave me hard time even from its tomb on my computer. It is much less stable compared to Mac OSX's homebrew.

```
Configured for 'x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'.

  Where should the build process find the source code?    .
  What compiler should emacs be built with?               gcc -g3 -O2
  Should Emacs use the GNU version of malloc?             yes
      (Using Doug Lea's new malloc from the GNU C Library.)
  Should Emacs use a relocating allocator for buffers?    no
  Should Emacs use mmap(2) for buffer allocation?         no
  What window system should Emacs use?                    x11
  What toolkit should Emacs use?                          GTK3
  Where do we find X Windows header files?                Standard dirs
  Where do we find X Windows libraries?                   Standard dirs
  Does Emacs use -lXaw3d?                                 no
  Does Emacs use -lXpm?                                   yes
  Does Emacs use -ljpeg?                                  yes
  Does Emacs use -ltiff?                                  yes
  Does Emacs use a gif library?                           yes -lgif
  Does Emacs use a png library?                           yes -lpng12
  Does Emacs use -lrsvg-2?                                yes
  Does Emacs use cairo?                                   no
  Does Emacs use imagemagick?                             yes
  Does Emacs support sound?                               yes
  Does Emacs use -lgpm?                                   yes
  Does Emacs use -ldbus?                                  yes
  Does Emacs use -lgconf?                                 yes
  Does Emacs use GSettings?                               yes
  Does Emacs use a file notification library?             yes -lglibc (inotify)
  Does Emacs use access control lists?                    yes -lacl
  Does Emacs use -lselinux?                               yes
  Does Emacs use -lgnutls?                                yes
  Does Emacs use -lxml2?                                  yes
  Does Emacs use -lfreetype?                              yes
  Does Emacs use -lm17n-flt?                              yes
  Does Emacs use -lotf?                                   yes
  Does Emacs use -lxft?                                   yes
  Does Emacs directly use zlib?                           yes
  Does Emacs have dynamic modules support?                no
  Does Emacs use toolkit scroll bars?                     yes
  Does Emacs support Xwidgets (requires gtk3)?            no
```